# How to specify custom port for Anchor deployment

Tags: anchor

I am currently developing on an intranet with other solana developers, and so to run my own test validator I’d need to specify a custom port on local host. However, I am not sure how to specify that on Anchor.toml.

Comment: I also attempted doing solana program deploy after specifying my url to localhost:<custom_port>, however I get the error `ConnectionError(Protocol(HttparseError(Version)))`

Comment: please elaborate this network infrastructure, how you're running the validator, etc.  none of this is clear.  a true "test validator" shouldn't even need a network connection so there are vital details missing here

Answer (score 3):

In your `Anchor.toml`:

```
[test.validator]
rpc_port = 1337
```

https://book.anchor-lang.com/anchor_references/anchor-toml_reference.html#testvalidator

Comment: thanks! however I still run into the ConnectionError(Protocol(HttparseError(Version))) error. I set my url to http://0.0.0.0:1337

Comment: Prefix your URL with `http` and try again.

Comment: That didn’t work

Comment: I found out that if I just changed the rpc-port of my validator and have a single validator running on my local network then it works just fine. However, I need to change both the rpc-port and the faucet-port if I want two separate validators running locally. How do I specify faucet port on Anchor toml? I tried faucet_port but it didnt work

Comment: The documentation says to use `faucet_port`, I'm not sure why it wouldn't work for you. In general, they're just the options that you can pass to `solana-test-validator`.